# which option is stronger when protect functions?

Tags: gcc

"-fstack-protector-all" and "-fstack-protector-strong", which is stronger?
gcc explain these options as follows:

```
-fstack-protector-all
    Like -fstack-protector except that all functions are protected.

-fstack-protector-strong
    Like -fstack-protector but includes additional functions to be protected --- those that have local array definitions, or have references to local frame addresses.
```

So, in my opinion, I think `-fstack-protector-all` is stronger, am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-fstack-protector-all` is "strongest", yes, but may be unnecessarily strong.

Roughly speaking:

- `-fstack-protector` protects functions that use reasonably large stack buffers.
- `-fstack-protector-strong` protects functions that use stack buffers of any size, even very small.
- `-fstack-protector-all` protects all functions.  This includes functions that do not use the stack at all and cannot possibly smash it, so in many cases it may impose a performance hit for no security gain.

For example:

```
void other_func(char *p);

void f1(void) {
}

void f2(void) {
    char buf[16];
    other_func(buf);
}

void f3(void) {
    char c;
    other_func(&c);
}
```

Using `-fstack-protector` adds protection to `f2` only.  `-fstack-protector-strong` adds it to `f2` and `f3`.  `-fstack-protector-all` adds it to all three functions, including `f1` which previously consisted only of `ret` and had no possible way to overflow anything, but now becomes about 10 instructions long.

[Try it on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/6e5Penhnj).

For more details, see the article ["'Strong' stack protection for GCC" by Jake Edge, LWN.net, February 5, 2014.](https://lwn.net/Articles/584225/)